# iOS stack Animations in series

Tags: ios, cabasicanimation

I would like to create a set of animations in **Series**.
For example

- Fade in for 2 seconds
- Rotate for 2 seconds
- Fade out for 2 seconds

What is the best way to achieve this?  I have tried to use the CAAnimation group but that seems to animate its array of animations in parallel.  I want a do animation 1 then do animation 2 and then do animation 3 (Series)

Comment: Use the animation group but deadly each animation until the previous should have ended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the block based animation for all animations like these.

For an animation like this the `animateKeyFrames` block would be perfect...

```
// set duration for the entire sequence of animations
[UIView animateKeyFramesWithDuration:6
                               delay:0
                             options:0
                          animations:^{
                              // add fade in keyframe
                              // starts at 0% lasts for 33% of animation
                              [UIView addKeyFrameWithRelativeStartTime:0
                                                      relativeDuration:0.333
                                                            animations:^{
                                                                view.alpha = 1.0;
                                                            }];
                              // add rotation key frame
                              // starts at 33% lasts for 33% of animation
                              [UIView addKeyFrameWithRelativeStartTime:0.333
                                                      relativeDuration:0.333
                                                            animations:^{
                                                                view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotationAngle);
                                                            }];
                              // add fade out key frame
                              // starts at 66% lasts for 33% of animation
                              [UIView addKeyFrameWithRelativeStartTime:0.666
                                                      relativeDuration:0.333
                                                            animations:^{
                                                                view.alpha = 0.0;
                                                            }];
                          }
                          completion:nil];
```

Comment: The fade in and fade out work fine - the rotate does not occur.  I do specify the rotate angle in Radians 6.28 for 360 degrees - Any suggestions.?

Comment: Ah, first you should use `M_PI` for pi then multiply it by 2. Not 6.28. Second, because 2 pi radians is the same as 0 it won't rotate. Split the rotate into two. One rotation to M_PI and the other rotation to 2* M_PI you'll have to update the timings too.

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays, you'd generally use `UIView` block animation via `animateKeyframesWithDuration`. Specify an animation duration of 6 seconds, and then add three calls to `addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime`, starting at relative start time of 0, 0.333, and 0.666, respectively, each with a duration of 0.333, and in those three animation blocks, do your appropriate animations.